# Regex working not quite as expected, matches unexpected string

Tags: javascript, regex

## Edit 2

Final regex: `/\b((https?:\/\/)?(www)?\S*\.\S*\b)/gim`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ytPUdh/1)

---

## Edit

Ended up with the following:

```
/\b((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}(\/[^\s]*)?\b)/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4NAHqJ/1)

This isn't quite enough, however, because this would also match something like the following:

```
as as das d youtube.com/as/ass asd asd
```

So to catch a̶l̶l̶ most cases, I do something like:

```js
const regex1 = /\b((^https?:\/\/)?(^www\.)?.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}(\/[^\s]*)?)\b/;
const regex2 = /((?!\s).)*$/;

let match1 = 'www.youtube.com/as/ass asd asd'.match(regex1);
let match2 = (match1?.[0] ?? '').match(regex2);
```

Conveniently, if a string has multiple URLs (such as `aaaa adsa youtube.com/a/b/c asdasd youtube.com/e/f/g`), the above approach extracts only the first one, which is exactly what I need, because I only generate one thumbnail preview per chat message.

Still however, this isn't a perfect solution, because -- as far as what I've been able to discover so far -- something like the following would be a false positive:

```js
const inputString = 'aaaa adsa ftssp://youtube.com/a/b/c asdasd https://youtube.com/e/f/g';

// result from above two matchers: `ftssp://youtube.com/a/b/c`
```

---

I've mixed in MANY answers from SO to come up with the following regex to match urls:

```js
const regex = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+$/
```

This works as expected except the string `test...`.

Why does this string match this regex (and potentially others, that I haven't encountered yet)?

```js
'test...'.match(regex) // true
'test..........'.match(regex) // true
```

Comment: _"Why doesn't this string match this regex"_ - you mean, why _does_ it? Because `[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+` - that character class contains the `.`, and you are allowing one to infinity occurrences of a character in that class, with the `+` quantifier ...

Comment: And if you didn't expect to match, can you give us the rules you wanted, at least roughly?

Comment: @cyberbrain I just want a regular web url matcher, I don't care for ftp and others. This one works well as is, it just... matches the string `test....` for some reason and I can't figure out why

Comment: @CBroe correct, I've update the OP

Comment: It allows `test...`, same as it would allow `test&&&` or `test@@@` or `test()(` - not sure if you wanted to match _any_ of these?

Comment: @CBroe No, I'd imagine urls would never contain something like that. I've removed the `+` quantifier, however it still matches... well, literally any word with dots after it. I've tried changing the end part to `[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=\.]`, still same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: In short, don't use regex to validate URLs. JS has [built-in support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for this, which you should probably use.

Comment: @InSync I've already seen that thread, I haven't found no one answer that matches all urls. Many don't match `youtube.com` -- also, I've considered using `new URL` as well, but it would throw an error for here as well: `new URL('youtube.com');`

Comment: @MikeK That's because `youtube.com` on its own is just a domain, not a valid URL. You can prepend `https://` as a crude fix.

Comment: @InSync I guess yeah, I could check for whether or not it exists and then prepend it before checking if it's a valid URL. Seems hacky, I might as well keep digging and find something else on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain your regex in prose text:

`^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+$`

`(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?` ... an optional group that matches `http://` or `https://` and you get the `s` into a group if it exists.

`[\w.-]+` ... one or more word characters (upper and lower case letters A-Z and all digits 0-9 and underscore `_`) or literal dot `.` or literal minus `-`

`(?:\.[\w.-]+)+` ... one or more of the following: a literal dot `.` followed by one or more word characters, dots, underscores (see previous paragraph)

`[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+` ... one or more of this long list:

- word character,
- literal minus `-`,
- literal dot `.`,
- underscore `_`,
- tilde `~`,
- colon `:`,
- forward slash `/`,
- question mark `?`,
- hash `#`,
- squared bracket open `[`,
- literal squared bracket close `]`,
- at sign `@`,
- exclamation mark,
- dollar sign `$`,
- ampersand sign `&`,
- single quote `'`,
- left parenthesis `(`,
- right parenthesis `)`,
- asterisk `*`,
- plus `+`,
- semicolon `;`,
- equals sign `=`

For "optimization" you could remove the second `.` inside the last long list (I didn't put it into my description) and also the explicit underscore as this is contained in the "word character" class.

Also the dot inside the group I described in the second paragraph could be removed if you want to match domain names with that.

Your strings `test...` and the like match, because the first non-capturing group for "http://" and "https://" is optional (followed by the question mark).

A regular expression that requires it (and includes the optimizations I mentioned above) could look like

```
^http(s)?:\/\/[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+[\w\-.~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+$
```

It is still very "messy", especially in the end when it comes to proper handling of port number, paths and query parameters. I found this in the [regex101 library](https://regex101.com/library/qV3iR4?orderBy=RELEVANCE&search=url), maybe it works better for you?

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)*(\/[\/\d\w\.-]*)*(?:[\?])*(.+)*
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very information indeed, however neither of the provided regular expressions would match `www.youtube.com` or `youtube.com` for example

Comment: because those are not URLs but just hostnames. You didn't write that you also want to match hostnames ;)

Comment: My apologies, I guess I missed that part. The original regex in the question matched it, so I clearly overlooked that to be as a requirement when I originally asked

Comment: Marked as accepted answer due to unclear original requirements, thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but: I think that "test..." etc. are also valid hostnames.

Comment: Also browsers just parse the URL instead of using a regex to verify them, so it could become a little harder to validate something the same way as a browser does.

Comment: I've updated the OP, got something kinda working :) I need this for a React-Native app, so the browser encoding the URL won't be a problem for my use case